# How to export Type DataTable (TVP) to a .csv or .xls file?

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, table-valued-parameters

I want to export TVP (Type of DataTable) to .csv file, or .xls, but more to .csv using aspx. Can you help me with this questuion?

Comment: I have no experience in exporting TVP, that's why I asked a question

Comment: @Marianna [google search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=33&gs_id=m&xhr=t&q=asp.net+datatable+export+to+excel&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=asp.net+datatable+export+to+excel&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=bc01b994c085c1e6&ion=1&biw=1163&bih=839) is the first step you need to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of ways by which you can achieve this. Just take a look into [my blog](http://www.naveenbhat.in/2012/06/export-data-to-excel-without-using.html). I specified 3 ways of doing it in my article.

- RenderControl
- HTML Table
- OLEDB

These are the ways of doing it without using the Interop.

---

> How to format my data during export time, for example color rows,
>   columns, headers and so on.

For this, I would like to quote these from my blog.

**RenderControl**

> Using this approach, we can easily export the data from GridView. This
>   will be useful when we want our exported data in the same format as in
>   the GridView.

Format your grid as required and invoke its `RenderControl` method. This will export style along with the data.

**HTML Table**

> Here the sheets are treated as a html table. The advantage of this
>   approach is  easy customization. You can customize the output using
>   any html tags.

Wrap `data` with `html style elements` and render it.

Comment: Thank you! I just want to concreate if tyour code works with large data?

Comment: Well, in that case you can [check this](http://www.naveenbhat.in/2012/06/dealing-with-large-data.html).

Comment: So great! Thank you, I liked your blog, it's very helpful, indeed. Sorry for such questions, but I'm a beginner and your team here helped me in some topics

Comment: The above link works well with large data. However, this is not the best approach as it brings data access logic into the business logic. If you have enough time better to concentrate on LINQ with Entity Framework.

Comment: Naveen, I and me team are going to use this one in our project! Thank you for solution! So I have one more question. Is it possible and how to format my data during export time, for example color rows, columns, headers and so on.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you. Please check the updated answer. If you like the answer, please consider by upvoting(^) it. You can upvote multiple answers, if proper.

Answer (score 1):

Simply bind your data to DataGrid and render page with `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";`

For further take a look [this](http://blog.weareon.net/export-datatable-to-excel-in-asp-net-without-using-excel-interop-part-ii/)